# Imageview not visible at linear layout

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to put an imageview inside my linear layout but it doesn't seem to show for some reason.

Here is my layout xml file -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frag_discover_search_image_view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_search_explore" />


    <com.omadahealth.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_discover_swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srl_direction="bottom">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/frag_discover_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/row_video_insta" />
    </com.omadahealth.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/progress_bar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my layout at the preview -

[image]

As you can see, at the top left of the view group there is a place for the image but I can't find the reason why it is invisible and un-clickable. Any ideas?

here is the 'ic_icon_search_explore' file -

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="16dp"
    android:height="16dp"
    android:viewportWidth="16"
    android:viewportHeight="16">
  <path
      android:pathData="M-4,-4h24v24h-24z"
      android:strokeAlpha="0"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillColor="#D8D8D8"
      android:fillType="nonZero"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"
      android:fillAlpha="0"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M6.8333,6.8333m-5.8333,0a5.8333,5.8333 0,1 1,11.6667 0a5.8333,5.8333 0,1 1,-11.6667 0"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:strokeWidth="1.5"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M15,15L10.9556,10.9556"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:strokeWidth="1.5"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Provide weight to your `ImageView`.

Comment: Use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src` because it is svg file.

Comment: A kind advise, use ConstraintLayout instead of Linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not visible because you are set padding inside the ImageView, Paddings are compress image by size. When You set vector image height width then set ImageView Height width as **wrap_content**

**Remove padding:-**

> ```
> android:paddingStart="16dp"
> android:paddingEnd="16dp"
> ```

**Try this ImageView:-**

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/frag_discover_search_image_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_search_explore" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> use this drawable. You have to just change the color of an icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="16dp"
        android:height="16dp"
        android:viewportWidth="16"
        android:viewportHeight="16">
    <path
            android:pathData="M-4,-4h24v24h-24z"
            android:strokeAlpha="0"
            android:strokeWidth="1"
            android:fillColor="#000"
            android:fillType="nonZero"
            android:strokeColor="#00000000"
            android:fillAlpha="0"/>
    <path
            android:pathData="M6.8333,6.8333m-5.8333,0a5.8333,5.8333 0,1 1,11.6667 0a5.8333,5.8333 0,1 1,-11.6667 0"
            android:strokeLineJoin="round"
            android:strokeWidth="1.5"
            android:fillColor="#00000000"
            android:strokeColor="#000"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
    <path
            android:pathData="M15,15L10.9556,10.9556"
            android:strokeLineJoin="round"
            android:strokeWidth="1.5"
            android:fillColor="#00000000"
            android:strokeColor="#000"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
</vector>
```

Your image is clearly visible but the color of the image is white so it's not showing in layout.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your layout

The issue is in your `ic_icon_search_explore` icon color

The color of your icon and your layout is white that's why your icon is not showing in layout

Just change the icon color of your `ic_icon_search_explore` it will work

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="16dp"
        android:height="16dp"
        android:viewportWidth="16"
        android:viewportHeight="16">
    <path
            android:pathData="M-4,-4h24v24h-24z"
            android:strokeAlpha="0"
            android:strokeWidth="1"
            android:fillColor="#D8D8D8"
            android:fillType="nonZero"
            android:strokeColor="#00000000"
            android:fillAlpha="0"/>
    <path
            android:pathData="M6.8333,6.8333m-5.8333,0a5.8333,5.8333 0,1 1,11.6667 0a5.8333,5.8333 0,1 1,-11.6667 0"
            android:strokeLineJoin="round"
            android:strokeWidth="1.5"
            android:fillColor="#00000000"
            android:strokeColor="#ff00"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
    <path
            android:pathData="M15,15L10.9556,10.9556"
            android:strokeLineJoin="round"
            android:strokeWidth="1.5"
            android:fillColor="#00000000"
            android:strokeColor="#ff00"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
</vector>
```